# How to convert my provices more quickly?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I have the following problem: I started as Teutonic Order and I wanted to create Prussia. Therefore you need to convert to Protestantism. When the big wave came and the provinces started to convert automatically I couldn't change my state religion because of the increasing instability caused by it - I was at war.

A couple of years later I switched the religion to Protestantism and changed my country to Prussia.

But I have to convert EVERY SINGLE county in my country with my missionary. I just have one and the quickest provinces take about 20 months to convert. I think for the last 100 years my troups do nothing but slaughter catholic rebels - even though I have an overall stability of 2 or 3.

There must be some way to do this more quickly, right? My neighbouring countries basically switched over night - including their provices.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Another issue entirely is that you probably switched religion too quickly -- during the first 50 years of Reformation, provinces within the German culture group switch spontaneously on their own, and at a decent rate. This process is slowed down, however, if you are the Defender of Faith for the Catholic faith or the Curia controller. Usually, it's best to switch when approximately half (or at least the most expensive ones) of your provinces have switched religion, so that you won't suffer from low religious unity and increased revolt risk.

Comment: The problem is that the provinces never switched. I think after 3 provinces the reformation stopped. I waited about 150 years I think but nothing happended...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides stability, which you said you are keeping high, there are four main ways to improve conversions.

1. For converting large areas, your best weapon is **the Religious idea group**. Among its ideas are one giving +3% to conversions and one that gives an extra missionary. However, consider the opportunity cost - there are more valuable admin idea groups than Religious (I would usually rather have Innovative or Administrative ideas, for instance).
2. If you have the money (500 ducats) and the military strength to back it up, you can get an extra missionary by declaring yourself **defender of the faith**. You lose the title when you lose any war, so be careful.
3. Western nations also have many **decisions** which can strengthen missionaries by 1% each. Two of them (Act of Uniformity and Advancement of True Religion) cost nothing, while others reduce tolerance of heretics (i.e. Catholics and Reformed, for a Protestant nation), reduce taxes, or increase stability cost. If you don't want to go down the Religious ideas route, enacting some of these decisions can significantly speed up your conversion time.
4. Finally, if you are lucky and/or rich, you can hire an **inquisitor advisor** for +2% missionary strength.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I really did'nt miss anything important :)

Comment: Is the Inquisitor Advisor special or just another random (Administrative?)  Advisor bonus like +10% Trade Power?

Comment: @DavidHarkness: I don't know what you mean by a "special" advisor; all types of advisors occur randomly. Inquisitor is an administrative advisor.

Comment: @mmyers By "special" I meant something other than the normal mechanism of hiring a new Adm/Dipl/Mil advisor when the current one dies. I've never seen an advisor with that bonus and so wanted to double-check. That would have come in very handy in my first game as the Ottomans.